# Python.Как сохранить водимые данные в переменную

Tags: python, input, переменные

Нужна помощь. Хочу сделать бота в Telegram, который сохраняет все заметки , а потом по команде  их всех выводит.
Столкнулся с проблемой. при вводе данных input() , я могу сохранить в переменную, то что пользователь ввел, но это всего одно значение.
a = input(...)
print(a)
Но как сделать, чтобы человек все время вписывал значения и они сохранялись в разные перемены.
Заранее спасибо)))

Comment: сохраняйте в список

Comment: в цикле читайте вводимые строки в список или в словарь

Comment: или еще лучше освойте sqlite и сохраняйте туда. имхо будет гораздо лучше чтобы заметки хранились НЕ в боте, который может и прилечь...

Comment: В теории, я думаю надо создавать динамический массив строк. Вопрос только в том, как их сохранить эти заметки, поскольку если прервать скрипт, то все заметки, которые хранились в ОП, сотрутся.